# Ethernet does not have valid IP configuration

Tags: wireless-networking

Every time I change my internal IP address, it won't get saved.

I uninstalled my network card and reinstalled it, I tried to manually enter in the IP address but every time I enter it in and accept it then restart it blanks out the IP I entered in. 
If anyone knows a solution please help.

If I have to reset my computer I will.

I use LAN adapter. no wifi

Comment: you can keep it auto and avoid manual IP entering. Also can you please explain some more?your question is not very clear

Comment: My computer was working fine until yesterday it showed a yellow triangle with an explanation on it. My hard wired network shows unidentified network, I ran the troubleshooter and there's an error that says Ethernet does not have valid IP configuration. I proceeded to look up solutions tried everything I found and nothing seems to fix this issue

Comment: did you tried like this? https://pasteboard.co/HcaM4aw.png

Comment: Yea that's what I did tried keeping it on auto then tried putting in googles IP and DNS but they didn't stay in they disappeared

Comment: if your settings aren't saving, then it could be something else. could be a virus.try scanning your computer with a good security software

Comment: Googling around, there are a few people with the same problem, and it seems like it's a corrupted registry entry. Try finding and deleting `My computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\Config` then do a reboot. It's supposed to recognise the entry as missing and then rebuild it correctly. {[reference](http://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/168091-Fixed-IP-disappears-from-NIC-GUI)}. (If this works I'll change it to an answer.)

Comment: Wizongod I got all the way to network tab but there is no config folder

Comment: Or a config file

Comment: This is my problem: but I've tried everything http://troubleshooter.xyz/wiki/fix-ethernet-doesnt-have-a-valid-ip-configuration/